# Problem with Parity setting in Serial Communication on Raspberry PI in C

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I send the bytes from Raspberry PI and receive them on my laptop through the serial communication ports using a terminal program. The parameters of the communication are as follow:

Baud rate: 9600, Data bits: 8, Parity: ODD, Stop bit: 1, Handshaking: None.

After sending two bytes `{0x10, 0x05}` I receive on the terminal (in my laptop) `{0x10, 0xC1}`. I can receive the correct bytes only if I change parity on the terminal to NONE.

How can I operate with my parity set to `ODD`?

See my code bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{

    struct termios RSopt;
    char str[3] = { 0x10, 0x05, 0x0};
    int fd;
    fd = open( "/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY );    

    tcgetattr( fd, &RSopt);
    cfmakeraw( &RSopt);
    cfsetspeed ( &RSopt, (speed_t)B9600);
    RSopt.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;  
    RSopt.c_cflag |= CS8;     
    RSopt.c_cflag |= PARENB;  
    RSopt.c_cflag |= PARODD; 
    RSopt.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 
    tcflush( fd, TCIFLUSH );
    tcsetattr ( fd, TCSANOW, &RSopt); 

    write( fd, str, 2 );
    close( fd );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ttyS0 on the Raspberry PI systems is the mini-uart, which does not support a parity bit.  See: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

The code you posted is otherwise basically correct.  I don't have an RPi accessible at the moment, but if the drivers are implemented correctly, you should be able to also verify correct application of the attributes by checking the return value of tcsetattr(), and also verifying the changes by checking the values set by tcgetattr(), as setattr may only indicate failure if NONE of the attributes are able to be set.